I2C Timeout Error on DE2-115 Board with ADS1115
I am working on a school project to build a 'weather station' out of a DE2-115 FPGA board and after covering almost everything, the project will not work with I2C.
I am using a NIOS-II to run the I2C block provided. I got the help of my professor, basically copying the way he implemented his NIOS-II to work with I2C, but the status return of the I2C program keeps being 'TIMEDOUT'.
My code is below. I have checked with my professor that the wiring of my board is correct, so it is most likely a coding issue.
#include <stdio.h>
#include "altera_avalon_pio_regs.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <system.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "altera_avalon_i2c.h"
#include "io.h"
//#include "ASD115.h"


int main() {
    ALT_AVALON_I2C_DEV_t *i2c_dev; //pointer to instance structure
    ALT_AVALON_I2C_STATUS_CODE status;
    ALT_AVALON_I2C_MASTER_CONFIG_t cfg;
    alt_u8 txbuffer[0x200];
    alt_u8 rxbuffer[0x200];
    char switch_in, ledg_out, ledr_out;

    //ADC Variables
    int16_t ADCAddr = 0x48;
    int16_t AHTAddr = 0x38;
    //Register 00 inside the ADS111 is the conversion register, that will contain the conversion from the ADC

    //Process Variables
//  int16_t digitalTemp, humidity;
    int16_t analogTemp, temp;
    int8_t Hex_addr[4];

    //get a pointer to the Avalon I2C Host Controller instance
    i2c_dev = alt_avalon_i2c_open("/dev/i2c_0");
    if (NULL == i2c_dev) {
        printf("Error: Cannot find /dev/i2c_0\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Opened /dev/i2c_0 \n");
    }

    printf("Configuring ADC...");

    alt_avalon_i2c_master_config_get(i2c_dev, &cfg);
    alt_avalon_i2c_master_config_speed_set(i2c_dev, &cfg, 100000);
    alt_avalon_i2c_master_config_set(i2c_dev, &cfg);

    //configuration for ADC
    alt_avalon_i2c_master_target_set(i2c_dev, ADCAddr);
    txbuffer[0] = 0x01;
    status = alt_avalon_i2c_master_tx(i2c_dev, txbuffer, 1, ALT_AVALON_I2C_NO_INTERRUPTS);

    usleep(10000);
    txbuffer[0] = 0x04;
    txbuffer[1] = 0x83;
    status = alt_avalon_i2c_master_tx(i2c_dev, txbuffer, 2, ALT_AVALON_I2C_NO_INTERRUPTS);
    usleep(10000);

    if (status != ALT_AVALON_I2C_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Failed: %d \n", status);
        } else {
            printf("finished.\n");
        }


    while (1)
    {
        //set the address of the device (ADC address is 0x48 or 0x49)
        alt_avalon_i2c_master_target_set(i2c_dev, ADCAddr);
        usleep(1000);

        switch_in = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(SWITCHES_BASE); // for debugging only
        ledg_out = switch_in;
        ledr_out = switch_in;
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(LEDGS_BASE, ledg_out);
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(LEDRS_BASE, ledr_out);

        //This command writes the register address into the necessary pointer
        usleep(10000);
        txbuffer[0] = 0x00; // read analog temperature
        status = alt_avalon_i2c_master_tx_rx(i2c_dev, txbuffer, 1, rxbuffer, 2, ALT_AVALON_I2C_NO_INTERRUPTS);
        usleep(10000);
        //Checks to see if the pointer address is successfully sent.
        if (status != ALT_AVALON_I2C_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Failed To Communicate with ADC: %d \n", status);
        } else {
            printf("Successfully Communicated with ADC: %d \n", status);
        }

        analogTemp = rxbuffer[1];
        analogTemp += rxbuffer[2];
        temp = (analogTemp-500)/10;

        printf("%d\n", temp);

        usleep(1000000);

        //Communicates with Digital Thermometer
        alt_avalon_i2c_master_target_set(i2c_dev, AHTAddr);

        usleep(1000);
        //Asks for Status Bit (Looking for 0x18)
        txbuffer[0] = 0x71;
        status = alt_avalon_i2c_master_tx_rx(i2c_dev, txbuffer, 1, rxbuffer, 1, ALT_AVALON_I2C_NO_INTERRUPTS);

        if (*rxbuffer == 0x18)
        {
            //Send 0xAC - Tells Thermometer to Measure
            txbuffer[0] = 0xAC;
            txbuffer[1] = 0x03;
            txbuffer[2] = 0x00;
            status = alt_avalon_i2c_master_tx(i2c_dev, txbuffer, 3, ALT_AVALON_I2C_NO_INTERRUPTS);

            usleep(250000);

            status = alt_avalon_i2c_master_rx(i2c_dev, rxbuffer, 7, ALT_AVALON_I2C_NO_INTERRUPTS);

            //Check if status bit7 is low
            if (rxbuffer[0] < 0x7F)
            {
                usleep(1000);
            } else {
                usleep(100000);
            }

            int16_t humidityMask = 0xF0*rxbuffer[3];
            int16_t temperatureMask = 0x0F*rxbuffer[3];
            int8_t humidity[3], temperature[3];

            humidity[0] = rxbuffer[1];
            humidity[1] = rxbuffer[2];
            humidity[2] = humidityMask;

            temperature[0] = rxbuffer[4];
            temperature[1] = rxbuffer[5];
            temperature[2] = temperatureMask;

            int16_t RelativeHumidity = *humidity * 50;
            //int8_t DigitalTemperature = *temperature * 100 - 50;

            Hex_addr[2] = RelativeHumidity*0x0F;
            Hex_addr[3] = RelativeHumidity*0xF0;
            //Hex_addr[2] = DigitalTemperature;
        } else {
            //Configure registers 0x1B, 0x1C, and 0x1E
        }

        if (status != ALT_AVALON_I2C_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Failed To Communicate with AHT: %d \n", status);
        } else {
            printf("Successfully Communicated with AHT: %d \n", status);
        }

        //Display to HEX
        //Hex_Base is a 32-bit number, which we only care about the first 15 bits. The first 8 bits is the analog temperature,
        //and the second 8 bits is the digital humidity
        Hex_addr[0] = temp*0x0F;
        Hex_addr[1] = temp*0xF0;
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(HEX_BASE, Hex_addr);

        usleep(1000000);
    }

    return 0;
}

I am using a Hexadecimal display block (which works) and switches and leds PIO (Parallel IN OUT) block which also works. Currently not even the I2C enable for SCL and SDA aren't triggering, if that helps.
I would appreciate the help! This is my final project for this class, Digital Systems (4000 lvl class), and my professor hasn't been helpful when he has looked over my stuff sadly.
Thanks,
Peter

As a heads up, the two different peripherals I am trying to control are an ADS1115 ADC and a AHT21 Temperature and Humidity Sensor, which I have hooked up both to 3.3v VCC and common GND.

Long ago. I tried to setup my BeMicro FPGA (MAX10) board to read a sensor with I2C. I use the I2C IP core. The IP core didn't set up the code (Verilog or VHDL) to enable the hardware output buffers for the I2C. I could never figure out how to enable those buffers in code so the NIOS code never worked.  I gave up because I my Verilog was pretty rusty. Are u using the IP core with the Cyclone IV and does it setup the hardware I2C output buffers?
